Entity Framework Core 8 DateOnly and DateTime comparison
I recently upgraded from EF Core 7 to EF Core 8, and because I do scaffolding models from the database (database-first approach), now I have DateOnly data types instead of DateTime for date columns.
The problem I have is that now I cannot compare DateOnly and DateTime inside the where statement because the compiler thinks it's two different types.
How can I resolve this?
var a = await DBContext.TableA
                       .Where(u => u.DateTimeColumn != u.DateOnlyColumn)
                       .ToArrayAsync();

Where DateTimeColumn is DateTime in the model and SQL Server, while DateOnlyColumn is DateOnly? (nullable) in the model and Date (nullable) in SQL Server.
If I'm comparing a SQL Server column and a parameter, I convert the DateTime parameter to DateOnly before the query, but I have a problem comparing two columns (DateTime and Date).

You can opt out of the mapping to DayeOnly with EF Core Power Tools

Have you tried converting the DateTimeColumn to DateOnly as shown in the example below?
var a = await DBContext.TableA
                       .Where(u => DateOnly.FromDateTime(u.DateTimeColumn) != u.DateOnlyColumn)
                       .ToArrayAsync();

You can convert DateTime to DateOnly using DateOnly.FromDateTime

Thanks! This works! The only problem with this is now, if it's nullable, like in my situation, I need to add a condition to check if DateTimeColumn is nullable or not. But it works like a charm!
